# Reveal a hidden image without javascript

Tags: html, css, image

I saw many questions where people were hiding/revealing images using jQuery, but I don't have jQuery installed and I would far prefer to use Html/css?

Is there a way to reveal an image when clicking on a button without using any javascript?

Comment: you can easily "install" jQuery by just adding this line inside your <head></head> section: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

It's not really installing, actually. You are referencing a jQuery file which happens to be hosted online by Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Gnuey said, it's easy to install jQuery just by referencing it from a host. Both google and Microsoft host jQuery, but most people use google. I recommend you check his comment for more info.

Actually, @Dipesh Parmar you can make this work in pure css, but you need a but of a work around:

Give the image an id, then make the button go to that id:

```
<a href="/#revealonclick"><button>Click to reveal image</button></a>
<img alt="" id="revealonclick" src="/image/pic.png">
```

Then in the CSS of the image:

```
#revealonclick{
    display: none;
}

#revealonclick:target{
    display: inline;
}
```

Yep. It's possible. CSS3 is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `checkboxes` to toggle click.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle">Click me!</label>
<img src="http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/232318/232318,1264892711,1/stock-photo-sleeping-pug-puppy-45602341.jpg" alt="" />
```

**CSS**

```
img{display:none;}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ img {
    display:block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acE5S/).

Answer (score 0):

clicking on DOM is a browser `event` and `css` can not handle such `events` so you need to use `client-side` script such as **javascript** ,**jQuery** or **mootools** etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do that. Just use pure Javascript without any libraries.

There are some CSS events, most common is :hover, but in your case :active is the closest one. However. there are no good way of doing this with pure CSS. Here is a link too what you can do with only CSS:

http://www.ryancollins.me/?p=1041

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic form of JavaScript as follows:(if you seriously are against **installing** jQuery)

```
function toggleImage() {
    var imgId = document.getElementById('image');
    imgId.style.visibility = (imgId.style.visibility === "hidden" || imgId.style.visibility === "") ? "visible" : "hidden";
}
```

Where the HTML is

```
<img id="image" src="http://i458.photobucket.com/albums/qq305/Ellerwind1982/souleater5.jpg" />
<button id="sth" onclick="javascript: toggleImage();">Hi</button>
```